# IE8, compatibility view on local files?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, web-standards

I just developed a small website and tested it locally in IE8, there is no compatibility view button but under settings i find an option called *"display intranet sites in compatibility view"*, this option is checked so i trust that all local files are rendered as IE7.

I then upload the page to my server and everything works fine in IE8-mode, now the the comp-view button is visible, i click it and my design becomes fubar!

I go to the settings for comp-view and uncheck the "display intranet sites in compatibility view", the site still looks ok when i try to browse it directly from the hdd and there is still no comp-view button visible.

This time i managed to create a fix in my css quite easily but i don't want to experience this again for a larger website.

How can i get BOTH IE8-mode and compatibility view for local pages and can i trust that it is active or not?

Comment: IE8 and IE7 shouldn't be that big of a difference, so I have to ask - do you have a DOCTYPE declared?

Comment: Theres a pile of differences between IE8 and IE7 if you have a DOCTYPE set.  If not you are running in Quirks mode and yes, they are almost the same.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you load files off your C:\ (e.g. that kind of local) then yes, you are forced into IE8 standards mode. In this case, the only way to toggle it is to use the Developer Tools <kbd>F12</kbd> and toggle it there, by doing the following:

1. Press F12 to access the Developer Tools. A new pane will appear at the bottom of the browser window
2. On the left menu, scroll down to the final option (Emulation). Or, press <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd>
3. Set the Document Mode to the desired browser version.

[image: IE Developer Tools Example]

If by local you mean off a webserver running on your PC or on a PC in your network (e.g. Intranet) then you can add it/them to the list of sites... they will then provide the icon on the address bar to toggle it.

I presume based on your description that you are seeing significant changes thus I presume you have set a DOCTYPE.  Can you verify this for us?

Comment: I'm loading the files from the filesystem, i have a doctype, and fubar might have been an overstatement. When working with IE my temperament for some reason seem to change...
Pressing F12 solved the problem, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I don't see why they'd disable that option for local files.

Answer (score 2):

I use this Meta Tag in IE8 to emulate IE7. If there is a Quirksmode Doctype, then this tag will not work.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

You can Use the *+html CSS hack under IE8.

Comment: this won't affect the face IE thinks you are on an intranet :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the "Display intranet sites in compat" try checking the "display ALL sites in compat". Thats what I usually do and it seems to work ok.